# Upgrading Python 2.7 to 3.7 and implementing zeep for SOAP calls

Tags: python, python-3.7, zeep

Upgrading to Python 3.7 and need to implement zeep for SOAP calls.

I am running into this issue:

`AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'factory'`

Code:

```
from zeep.client import Client

class UpgradePython(object):

    def __init__(self, wsdl, api_code):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        logging.getLogger('zeep.client').setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.client = Client(wsdl)
        self.api = api_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue with the library `zmq` after I update from python 3.4 to 3.7. What I did is I create a new environment and reinstall all the libraries using:

First, get the environment file:

```
conda env create -n new_env python=3.7
```

Then use the new environment: `conda activate new_env`

Reinstall all the libraries.

Comment: There's nothing in the question suggesting that they use anaconda.